# Keytool - Generate AES Public/Private Key Pair

Tags: aes, keytool

How can I use keytool to generate a public/private AES key? I can only find references to generate from code or generate a keystore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES is an algorithm to generate symmetric key, not a asymmetric key pair (public and private key).

Some of the other algorithms to generate a symmetric key are: `DES, 3DES`.

Algorithms to generate an asymmetric key pair are: `RSA, DSA, EC`.

If you are planning to generating a key pair, you can use the `-genkeypair` command. Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_genkeypair).

If you want to generate a symmetric key, you can use the `-genseckey` command. Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_genseckey).